# Empty Object on React useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my project I have the component ExportSearchResultCSV. Inside this component the nested component CSVLink exports a CSV File.

```
const ExportSearchResultCSV = ({ ...props }) => {

    const { results, filters, parseResults, justify = 'justify-end', fileName = "schede_sicurezza" } = props;

    const [newResults, setNewResults] = useState();
    const [newFilters, setNewFilters] = useState();
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const [headers, setHeaders] = useState([])

    const prepareResults = () => {
        let newResults = [];

        if (results.length > 1) {
            results.map(item => {
                newResults.push(parseResults(item));
            }); return newResults;
        }
    }

    const createData = () => {

        let final = [];
        newResults && newResults?.map((result, index) => {
            let _item = {};
            newFilters.forEach(filter => {
                _item[filter.filter] = result[filter.filter];
            });
            final.push(_item);
        });
        return final;
    }


    console.log(createData())
    

    const createHeaders = () => {
        let headers = [];
        newFilters && newFilters.forEach(item => {
            headers.push({ label: item.header, key: item.filter })
        });

        return headers;
    }

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setNewFilters(filters);
        setNewResults(prepareResults());
        setData(createData());
        setHeaders(createHeaders());
    }, [results, filters])

    return (
        <div className={`flex ${justify} h-10`} title={"Esporta come CSV"}>
            {results.length > 0 &&
                <CSVLink data={createData()}
                    headers={headers}
                    filename={fileName}
                    separator={";"}
                    onClick={async () => {
                        await setNewFilters(filters);
                        await setNewResults(prepareResults());
                        await setData(createData());
                        await setHeaders(createHeaders());
                    }}>
                    <RoundButton icon={<FaFileCsv size={23} />} onClick={() => { }} />
                </CSVLink>}
        </div >

    )
}

export default ExportSearchResultCSV;
```

The problem I am facing is the CSV file which is empty. When I log createData() function the result is initially and empty object and then it gets filled with the data. The CSV is properly exported when I edit this component and the page is refreshed. I tried passing createData() instead of data to the onClick event but it didn't fix the problem. Why is createData() returning an empty object first? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You call `console.log(createData())` in your functional component upon the very first render. And I assume, upon the very first render, `newFilters`  is not containing anything yet, because you initialize it like so `const [newFilters, setNewFilters] = useState();`.
That is why your first result of `createData()` is an empty `object`(?). When you execute the `onClick()`, you also call `await setNewFilters(filters);` which fills `newFilters` and `createData()` can work with something.

You might be missunderstanding `useEffect()`. Passing something to `React.useEffect()` like you do

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    setNewFilters(filters);
    setNewResults(prepareResults());
    setData(createData());
    setHeaders(createHeaders());
 }, [results, filters]) <-- look here
```

means that `useEffect()` is only called, when `results` or `filters` change. Thus, it gets no executed upon initial render.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I will let u know